# Create USB install stick from Mojave

Tags: mojave

Since macOS Mojave moved the OS install to its system preferences and you can't download installers directly anymore, how would you go about creating an Mojave USB stick from Mojave onwards?

Comment: Its impossible to tell until 10.15 is in beta.

Comment: What JBis said. Apple may do **BETA** software installs/updates differently than the released version. We will all find out when they release macOS Mojave. It would be good to wait a day or so after that as many people who are paid to write about Macs will likely have info on creating a stand alone installer.

Comment: @JBis, You said, "Its impossible to tell until 10.15 is in beta.", why do we have to wait until 10.15 is in beta, 10.14 will be out long before 10.15. :)

Comment: @user3439894 Mojave is released from the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

Seems they added the installer recently to the new App Store on Mojave. If you search for `macos mojave` the installer shows up in the results under the "Utilities" category.