# Where does Mojave download the Mojave installer?

Tags: macos, mac, mac-appstore, mojave, bootable-disk

Similar to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335358/create-usb-install-stick-from-mojave), I would like to understand where Mojave is downloading itself when I download it from the [App store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-mojave/id1398502828?mt=12).

The Application folder doesn't have anything like `Install MacOs Mojave` or similar.

Comment: Can you go to App Store page for macOS Mojave (https://itunes.apple.com/app/macos-mojave/id1398502828) and check if it is downloaded? It's downloaded in the `/Applications` folder in the root directory of hard disk and not `~/Applications` folder in the Home directory.

Comment: Nope, it's not there. Not in `/Applications` nor in `~/Applications`

Comment: It won't be moved to there until the download is finished. It's well-hidden away until then; & is also deleted after you've run the installer.

Comment: Weird.  On my system I see it in `/Applications/Install macOS Mojave.app`